# Add colour scale to axis of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to know if there's a ggplot function to add a colour scale to the axis of a plot.

I don't have a reproducible example, but please see the attached image which is a plot I produced using ggplot, which I have then saved and added a colour scale to the y-axis manually in MS powerpoint. The colour scale is not intended to extend all the way up the y-axis, just a small section.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgYHH.jpg)

I'd prefer to add the colour scale to my plot in R if there is a way to do it

The code for this particular plot is pretty long as there's quite a few customised elements, so if we can base the answer just on a simple bar graph such as:

```
bargraph<-ggplot(data=mydf, aes(x=category, y=value)+
          geom_bar()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sure could this be achieved but I don't know of any easy and general approach and hence at least for the approach below it requires some fiddling to position the legend and to set the height of the colorbar. Note that all these values are also dependent on the size you use when exporting your plot.

Basic idea is to first extract the legend using `cowplot::get_legend()` then place the legend on top of the axis (text) using `annotation_custum` where we have to set `clip="off"`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = cyl)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_color_gradient2(midpoint = 6)

legend <- (p +
  labs(color = NULL) +
  theme(
    legend.text = element_blank(),
    legend.background = element_blank(),
    legend.box.margin = margin(),
    legend.key.height = unit(30, "pt"),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt"),
    legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "pt")
  )) |>
  cowplot::get_legend()

xmax <- min(mtcars$hp) -
  .05 * diff(range(mtcars$hp)) -
  20

cols <- rep("black", 6)
cols[c(1, 3)] <- "white"

p +
  guides(color = "none") +
  annotation_custom(
    legend,
    xmin = -Inf, xmax = xmax,
    ymin = 10, ymax = 20
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(
    color = cols
  ))
```

[image]